# Delphi XE4 iOS can a background app be built in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2, delphi-xe4

I need to build a project for iOS that must run in the background and ideally start automatically when the phone is powered up or restarted, is this possible in Delphi XE4 or do I have to use xcode?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you can specifically achieve in XE4 but background apps in iOS have some limitations. You can't automatically start something when powering up or restarting, and most applications are only allowed to run a short task after closing.

The only exceptions to this are an application in the following categories:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background,
  such as a music player app
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such
  as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Newsstand apps that need to download and process new content
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories